# Is it possible to add a Group to another Group (as Sub/Nested Group) through Apex - Trigger/Batch?

Tags: apex, roles

Is it possible to add a Group to another Group (as Sub/Nested Group) through Apex - Trigger/Batch?. Also want to know the possibility to add a Role into a Group.

Any thoughts ??

Answer (score 7):

You can use the GroupMember object for this. A GroupMember can either be a User or a Group.
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_groupmember.htm

```
Group parentGroup = [Select Id From Group Where Name = 'ParentGroupName'];
Group childGroup = [Select Id From Group Where Name = 'ChildGroupName'];
GroupMember gm = new GroupMember(GroupId = parentGroup.Id, UserOrGroupId = childGroup.Id);
insert gm;
```

To add a role into a Group via APEX, use the automatically created Group for the Role (a Group with Type 'Role' and relatedId = roleId). Then add the Group as a GroupMember to the parent Group.

```
UserRole theRole = [Select Id From UserRole Where Name = 'theRoleName';
Group roleGroup = [Select Id, Name, Type From Group Where Type = 'Role' AND relatedId = :theRole.Id];
GroupMember gm = new GroupMember(GroupId = parentGroup.Id, UserOrGroupId = roleGroup.Id);
insert gm;
```

Comment: Getting message- **Group.RelatedId** not  Writable -when inserting Group with Type Role. Please suggest!!

Comment: Any suggestions on this?

Comment: How to insert a group through apex with type Role and related Id of a role?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot that the role-group is automatically created whenever you create a role. Actually there are multiple groups created for each role: 'Role' 'RoleAndSubordinates', 'RoleAndInteralSubordinates' etc, depending on whether you have portals/communities. I updated my answer with this.

Comment: Really? You can add a group as a sub group using Apex? I thought a group couldn't be added to another group, but you're saying it can be done through Apex? It could be that I'm just behind on some of the platform updates of the last year, so wanted the clarification.

Comment: @crmprogdev it can also be done via the GUI. Not sure though if this is new or 'less new'. I only worked with it for the first time recently.

Comment: Apparently I needed to go back and revisit that material. Looked at the Force.com Fundamentals.PDF from Oct 2013 (last revision) and saw no mention of being able to nest Public Sharing Groups. However, it is explained in the March 2014 Security Implementation Guide PDF I had at hand. Always learning new things! ;)